# How to capitalize the first letter of a word starting with numbers

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'd like to find a way to capitalize the first letter of a word starting with numbers.

Input:

```
2019donaldtrump
03012019paris
```

Expected result:

```
2019Donaldtrump
03012019Paris
```

Is there a way to modify this command

```sh
sed -e 's/^\(.\)/\U\1/g'
```

to make it look for the first actual letter of the word?

Answer (score 8):

This appears to do what you want in my testing:

```
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\([a-z]\)/\1\U\2/g' input.txt
```

Input:

```
2019donaldtrump
03012019paris
```

Output:

```
2019Donaldtrump
03012019Paris
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by [Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto), the grouping is not actually necessary:

```
sed -e 's/[[:digit:]][a-z]/\U\0/g' input.txt
```

Comment: No needs for groups, `s/[[:digit:]][a-z]/\U\0/g` is working as well.

Answer (score 5):

One in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}/^[0-9]/ && match($0,/[a-z]/){$RSTART=toupper($RSTART)}1' file
```

Output:

```
2019Donaldtrump
03012019Paris
notstartingwith123
```

Explained:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=""                     # separators to empty
}
/^[0-9]/ && match($0,/[a-z]/) {   # if there is starting digit and lower case letters
    $RSTART=toupper($RSTART)      # capitalize the first letter
}1' file                          # output
```

Shorter, as `match` will return `RSTART` as its value, store and use that instead:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}/^[0-9]/&&r=match($0,/[a-z]/){$r=toupper($r)}1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<[[:digit:]]\+[[:alpha:]]/\U&/' file
```

This will uppercase the first alphabetic character of a word beginning with digits.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed for `\U`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/' file
2019Donaldtrump
03012019Paris
```

Comment: This will give upper case for any non alpha charters, even start of the line.  Op just what the change on text after  number.

Comment: @Jotne Correct but the sample input the OP provided shows that all of his lines contain 1 word and it starts with digits followed by lower case letters. I'm assuming the posted sample input is truly representative of the OPs real data and so there's no point coding for something that doesn't exist in the input, especially when there's many other things that COULD be present in the input and we can't write solutions for all of them.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  If this answer has caveats, that should be expressed in the answer itself (not in comments).

Comment: @mickmackusa No, it should not. Tiny, trivial scripts using constructs easily looked up in the man page are far more useful to anyone who doesn't understand them without spoon-feeding explanations of the constructs used. There are no caveats - the answer does what the OP wanted and, like every other answer posted, if it's not what they wanted then they should update the question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that includes cases where this or other answers don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try Perl

```
$ cat boby.txt
donald
2019donaldtrump
03012019paris

$ perl -pe ' s/\b\d+\K(.)(?=\S+)/uc $1/ge ' boby.txt
donald
2019Donaldtrump
03012019Paris
```

Explanation:

```
\b - Match word boundary
\d+  - Match digits
\K - Ignore the matched content that occured before i.e (\b\d+)
(.) - Match a single character Store it in $1
(?=\S+) - Match the rest of the chars till you get a space.
uc $1 - Use the upper case function and replace $1 with it. This can be done by adding "e" modifier i.e "/ge" at the last
```